# exchange header with payload and keep headers intact

Tags: groovy, spring-integration, spring-xd

I have a message payload coming with headers x ,y,z I want to remove the payload and make new payload as value of header y    and keep the headers x y z intact.I am trying this using groovy .messagePayload is a json string  which is value of header y

My new message = header x y x+ payload
where payload = valueof header y

```
def messagePayload  = parser.parseText(headers['y'])

def newHeaders = [:] 
newHeaders.putAll(headers)
return org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(messagePayload.toString()).copyHeaders(newHeaders).build()​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

??

`newHeaders['y'] = messagePayload.toString()` is simply replacing `headers['y']` with it's own value (`toString()`), determined by `def messagePayload  = parser.parseText(headers['y'])`

You don't show enough code but you need something like

```
newHeaders['y'] = originalPayload
```

**EDIT**

You said you wanted to **exchange** the header with the payload. If all you want to do is copy the payload to a header, use a header enricher

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="y" expression="payload" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

If you want to do it in code...

```
MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader("y", message.getPayload()).build;
```

**EDIT2**

Your question is still not clear; what does `parser.parseText(headers['y'])` do?

If you simply want to replace the message payload with one of the header values, use a transform:

```
<int:transform ... expression="headers['y']" />
```

The headers will remain unchanged.

If you want to to write it in java

```
 MessageBuilder.withPayload(headers.get("y")).copyHeaders(headers).build();
```

I guess in groovy it's

```
 MessageBuilder.withPayload(headers.['y']).copyHeaders(headers).build();
```

Comment: I  wanted to copy a value in header y as new payload. and keep all headers values intact

Comment: The title says you want to exchange the header and payload - see my edit if all you want to do is copy the header.

Comment: sorry may be i framed question wrong I updated my question please see above.

Comment: I am still not sure what you're tring to do `parser`. See my edit.

Comment: i wrote extra code   to do it  .Thanks for showing simple way.